# Python try except with if else - KeyError if no value for input of first condition is passed

Tags: python, if-statement, try-except

Assessment for the names "max" and "alex" should be overall **true**, iff all three inputs (healthy, tall, rich) are 1. If at least one of the inputs is equal to 0, then "false" should be returned.

However, it seems that a value for the input of the first condition (in this case healthy) always has to be passed in order not to get the KeyError. How can that be changed?

See in the following code snippet that for test 2 I get a KeyError. In comparison, for test 3 I provide a value for "healthy" and the result is as expected.

```
import pytest


def function(x: dict) -> str:
    try:
        if x["name"] in ["max", "alex"]:
            if x["healthy"] != 1:
                return "false"
            if x["tall"] != 1:
                return "false"
            if x["rich"] != 1:
                return "false"
        return "true"
    except KeyError:
        return "input_is_missing"


class TestEvaluate:
    false = "false"
    true = "true"
    input_is_missing = "input_is_missing"

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "inputs, expected",
        [
            # Test 1
            (
                {
                    "name": "max",
                    "healthy": 0,
                },
                false,
            ),
            # Test 2
            (
                {
                    "name": "max",
                    "tall": 0,
                },
                false,
            ),
            # Test 3
            (
                {
                    "name": "max",
                    "healthy": 1,
                    "tall": 0,
                },
                false,
            ),
        ],
    )
    def test_valid_inputs(self, inputs, expected):
        assert function(inputs) == expected
```

Comment: Can you provide an example that causes the error?

Comment: Are you passing any value for "healthy" when you pass the input tall = 0? If no value is provided for "healthy" and you try to access that in first condition to check its value, you get KeyError

Comment: Without you providing sample data it is not clear where your problem lies. But maybe this is useful: in order to avoid KeyError when a specific key such as 'healthy' is missing you could use `if x.get("healthy", 0) != 1:`  and so on which provides a default value triggering the missing input message.

Comment: @carphunter I have added an answer below based on your clarifications

Answer (score 1):

You need to first check if any of healthy, tall or rich are explicitly set as 0. If so, return false.

Once that's sorted, your only case when the return value is true is when all of them are available and are set to 1. In that case return true. When accessing the values, if any of them are missing, you will automatically get a KeyError and hence the response input_is_missing.

```py
def function(x: dict) -> str:
    try:
        if x["name"] in ["max", "alex"]:
            if "healthy" in x and x["healthy"] == 0:
                return "false"
            if "tall" in x and x["tall"] == 0:
                return "false"
            if "rich" in x and x["rich"] == 0:
                return "false"
            if x["healthy"] == 1 and x["tall"] == 1 and x["rich"] == 1:
                return "true"
    except KeyError:
        return "input_is_missing"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the construct `if "healthy" in x and ...`, but I suggest using the [get method of dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), which can return a default if the key does not exist.

Your code then becomes:

```py
def function(x: dict) -> str:
        if x["name"] in ["max", "alex"]:
            if x.get("healthy", 0) != 1:
                return "false"
            if x.get("tall", 0) != 1:
                return "false"
            if x.get("rich", 0) != 1:
                return "false"
        return "true"
```

That way, you will never get a `KeyError`, which might or might not be what you want.

Edit after comment, if you **do want** the "input_is_missing" return:

```py
def function(x: dict) -> str:
        if x["name"] in ["max", "alex"]:
            missing=[]
            for characteritic in ["healthy", "tall", "rich"]:
                if characteristic in x:
                    if x[characterictic] != 1:
                        return "false"
                else:
                    missing.append(characteritic)
            if missing:
                return "input_is_missing" # you even know which one
            else:
                return "true"
        return "true"
```

Comment: A KeyError would be desirable if I have the following inputs for example:
{"name": "max", "healthy": 1,"tall":1}. In this case I need a value for "rich" in order to give a final true or false"

Comment: @carphunter I added another option is you do want to know that a characteristic is missing.

Answer (score -1):

To address the issue of receiving a KeyError when the "healthy" input is missing, you can modify the code by checking for the presence of the "healthy" key in the input dictionary before accessing its value. Here's an updated version of the code:

```py
def function(x: dict) -> str:
    try:
        if x["name"] in ["max", "alex"]:
            
            # Check if the "healthy" key is present in the input dictionary
            if "healthy" not in x:
                return "false"

            if x["healthy"] != 1:
                return "false"
            
            if x["tall"] != 1:
                return "false"
            
            if x["rich"] != 1:
                return "false"
            
            return "true"
        
        return "false"

    except KeyError:
        return "input_is_missing"
```

In this updated code, if the "healthy" key is missing from the input dictionary, the function immediately returns "false" without checking the other conditions. This ensures that a KeyError is not raised and that the proper output is returned.

Comment: Thanks! But I want "healthy" to be treated just as the other inputs. So if ANY of those three inputs is 0, then false should be returned. If you'd change the order - say to "rich" as the first one - one would always get "input_missing" except for when a value for rich is passed.

Comment: @carphunter what would like to see as output if say your input is just `{"name": "max", "tall": 1}` ?

Comment: In that case -> input is missing. If "tall":0 it should be false